# Binding expression with StringFormat and uppercase Converter?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting, valueconverter

I have a [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) whose text is bound to live [ticker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354793/binding-to-datetime-now-update-the-value) (via `System.Date.Now`) and that binding contains a [`ValueConverter`](http://www.sytone.com/2010/08/wpf-converter-caseconverter/) that is supposed to convert the string to uppercase. However, the string does not result in uppercase letters (the result is as if the converter weren't even there). How do I get the binding result to be uppercase?

```
<TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Now,
                       Source={StaticResource ticker},  
                       StringFormat={}{0:dddd\, MMMM d}, 
                       Converter={StaticResource CaseConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

H.B. is correct.  You need a better converter:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Now, Source={StaticResource ticker}, Converter={StaticResource UpperCaseDateConverter}, ConverterParameter='dddd, MMMM d'}" />
```

Converter:

```
public class UpperCaseDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((DateTime)value).ToString((string)parameter).ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just came to the same conclusion (similar code, even). I was just about to post my answer, but yours is nice and succinct. :)

Comment: And I'd upvote your answer and H.B.'s but I have to wait til 15 rep

Answer (score 3):

The converter should be applied before the `StringFormat`, so if the `StringFormat` destroys it again you might want to move that formatting logic into the converter (or apply multiple converters using a group-converter of sorts).