# How can I pass a variable into a WPF Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm writing a WPF application that displays the status of a certain time-consuming task.

I have a TextBlock bound to the task's start time, and I have another TextBlock that is intended to display the amount of time spent on said task.

Using simple binding with a converter, I was able to get the second TextBlock to display the TimeSpan properly, but I'm not too crazy about this solution. I would like for the second TextBlock to update the TimeSpan as time continues.

For example, when the user loads the application, the second TextBlock would say "5 minutes", but 15 minutes later, it would still say "5 minutes", which is misleading.

I was able to find this solution ( [Binding to DateTime.Now. Update the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354793/binding-to-datetime-now-update-the-value) ), which is painfully close to what I want, but not quite there.

Is there any way I can pass the task's start time to this Ticker class and have the text update itself?

EDIT: Here's what I have so far:
C#:
    public class Ticker : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

```
    public Ticker()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public string TimeDifference
    {
        get
        {
            string timetaken = "";
            try
            {
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
                timetaken = (StartTime == default(DateTime)) ? "StartTime not set!" : ((ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours).ToString("N0") + " hours, " + ts.Minutes + " minutes, " + ts.Seconds + " seconds";
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return timetaken;
        }
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeDifference"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML:
`<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <TextBlock Text="Dataset started on:"/>

        <TextBlock Name="starttimeLabel" Text="10/23/2012 4:42:26 PM"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">

        <TextBlock Text="Time taken:"/>

        <TextBlock Name="timespanLabel" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ticker}, Path=TimeDifference, Mode=OneWay}"/>

    </StackPanel>`

Lastly, in my StatusPanel's Loaded event, I have the following:
Ticker.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(starttimeLabel.Text);

I apologize for the atrocious formatting, but I tried following the instructions to no avail (insert 4 spaces for code blocks, then tried using `<code></code>`, etc.)

Comment: what do you mean by task ? 
could you add some code ?

Comment: The definition of "task" in this context wouldn't impact the answer. However, tasks involve generating millions of images across a group of computers, so it can take several days. This is why I wan't to display the amount of time that the task has been processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DispatcherTimer "as" CountDown:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CountDown.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="initialTime" Width="50" Height="20" Margin="165,66,288,224"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtCountDown" Width="50" Height="20" Margin="236,66,217,225"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
    namespace CountDown
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private DispatcherTimer cDown;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                initialTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                TimeSpan timeToDie = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10); //Set the time "when the users load"
                txtCountDown.Text = timeToDie.ToString();

                cDown = new DispatcherTimer();
                cDown.Tick += new EventHandler(cDown_Tick);
                cDown.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                cDown.Start();
            }


            private void cDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TimeSpan? dt = null;
                try
                {
                    dt = TimeSpan.Parse(txtCountDown.Text);
                    if (dt != null && dt.Value.TotalSeconds > 0  )
                    {
                        txtCountDown.Text = dt.Value.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,-1)).ToString();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        cDown.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     cDown.Stop();
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, but not quite. I was hoping this could be done via binding in markup.